# Using socat to proxy abstract-namespace UNIX sockets across network namespaces

Tags: linux, network-namespace, unix-sockets

I have a system service that listens for commands on a UNIX domain socket in the abstract namespace.  I now need to access this from a process in another network namespace.  Because the socket is in the abstract namespace, it is network-namespace-specific.

I can sort of get this to work with socat:

```
socat ABSTRACT-CONNECT:@proxy-socket EXEC:'"ip netns exec my-netns socat STDIO ABSTRACT-LISTEN:@proxy-socket,nofork"'
```

This correctly listens on the socket in my namespace and proxies a connection through to the actual socket in the default namespace.  But it will only do it for one connection; once that connection is closed, socat will exit.

I could do it like this:

```
socat ABSTRACT-LISTEN:@prooy-socket,fork EXEC:'"ip netns exec default socat STDIO ABSTRACT-CONNECT @proxy-socket,nofork"'
```

if `ip netns exec` provided a way to exec a process in the default namespace, but it seems it doesn't.

Is there a better way of going about this?

Comment: If you use `nsenter` instead of `ip netns exec`, you can run a command in the global namespace with `nsenter -t1 -n socat ...` (this assumes that you're local namespace is just a network namespace, not a PID namespace). That means, "run a command in the network namespace of PID 1".

Comment: @larsks yes this is where I've ended up.  Thanks.  Seems weird that `ip netns exec` has no way to exec into the default namespace.

Answer (score 0):

What if instead of using an `EXEC` target in `socat`, you just use a shared filesystem location and a unix socket?

For example, if I have two network namespaces:

```
ip netns add red
ip netns add blue
```

And an abstract socket listening in `red`:

```
while :; do date; sleep 1; done |
ip netns exec red socat abstract-listen:@example,fork -
```

I can run a proxy that connects the abstract socket to a unix socket in a shared filesystem location:

```
ip netns exec red socat \
  abstract-connect:@example unix-listen:/tmp/socket,fork
```

And then in the `blue` namespace I can proxy that unix socket to an abstract socket:

```
ip netns exec blue socat \
  unix-connect:/tmp/socket abstract-listen:@example,fork
```

Now I can connect to the abstract socket in the `blue` namespace and see the data flowing into the abstract socket in the `red` namespace:

```
$ ip netns exec blue socat abstract-connect:@example -
Sun Jan 29 09:45:42 AM EST 2023
Sun Jan 29 09:45:43 AM EST 2023
Sun Jan 29 09:45:44 AM EST 2023
```